# change img src not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If somebody can tell me why this code fails to change the src of that image on a click of a link. It is very simple and easy for someone who knows javascript. I made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WWvfP/1/

```
<ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#" id="home_mic">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="services_mic">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="prices_mic">Prices</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="contact_mic">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="imageWrap">

<img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" id="mainImage" style=""/>

</div>

<script language="javascript">
  $("#home_mic").click(function(event){
  $("#mainImage").attr("src","http://placehold.it/80x40");
});</script>
```

Comment: It works, you forgot to include jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/WWvfP/2/

Comment: Yes it is indeed ok in jsfiddle, but on my site it is still not working. I have linked to the jquery in my head. Do I need something more besides <script language="javascript">...</script>?

Comment: Ok, it is working, I had to put the script after the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. You just didn't select jQuery as JS framework in the jsfiddle.

Corrected jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/WWvfP/4/

Comment: Yes it is indeed ok in jsfiddle, but on my site it is still not working. I have linked to the jquery in my head. Do I need something more besides <script language="javascript">...</script>?